# I am getting error because of scp script. Refresh SSH connection or scp without password. [vRO, JS]

Tags: javascript, ssh, vmware, scp

VM that i am using  is red hat 7 and
I am coding an automation in vRO.

```
session = new SSHSession(
hostname,
username,
port
);

session.connectWithPassword(password);

try {
session.executeCommand(command, true);

if (session.exitCode !== 0) {
//exception handling part...
}
```

And I am getting error when i write `command= scp file.txt remote_username@10.10.0.2:/remote/directory`

**ERROR MESSAGES:**

- stdout
- exitCode 1
- stderr   Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). lost connection
- error     "action name" has failed

It can be about scp. When i use scp ssh session is cutting and its asks for a password.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be about scp. When i use scp ssh session is cutting and its asks for a password.

You have not precised if scp works after giving a password. If giving a password will also not perform a copy with permission denied issue, this means your user do not have permission to this directory.

First of all check permission for remote directory like following:

1. SSH to your linux vm:

   ssh remote_username@10.10.0.2
2. Then check permissions on your directory with ls command:

   ls -lah /remote/directory

Directory should have write permission set for your user or for its group like below:

> drw-rw-r-- 1 remote_username remote_username 25 Feb 15 00:51 .

If you need to change permission you can use *chown/chmod* to manipulate dir owner like example below:

```
chown remote_username:remote_username /remote/directory
```

Or change dir permissions flags like:

```
chmod 664 /remote/directory
```

Or append write permission only for all users:

```
chmod +w /remote/directory
```

Be careful about security who can be allowed to read/write files in system.